# How to show dictionary data in table format in terminal

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to solve the simple usecase where I need to show data in terminal in tabular style not needed fancy table but somehow that emits like table.

here is my code.

```
score = {'rounds_0': {'jack': 9, 'joe': 8}, 'rounds_1': {'jack': 11, 'joe': 13}}

players_name = ["jack","joe"]
for each_rounds in range(0,2):
    print(f"""              ********Round {each_rounds + 1}****""", end='')
print()

for player, each_rounds in zip(players_name, range(0,2) ):
   print(player,score.get(f'rounds_{each_rounds}').get(player))
```

currently my output is as follows

```
              ********Round 1****              ********Round 2****
jack 9
joe 13
```

I am trying to include `round_0` dict value unders `Round 1` column and similary `Round 2` for `round_1`
like this and if possible sum of each row

```
              ********Round 1****              ********Round 2****          *****Total*****
jack                 9                                  11                       20
joe                  8                                  13                       21
```

I really tried some for loop concepts but can't figure out how I do it as I am really beginner in python any help will be really great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating players and rounds together, but what you need to do is iterate players and then rounds for each player. It's probably easier to generate a list of scores for each player and then print that:

```py
score = {'rounds_0': {'jack': 9, 'joe': 8}, 'rounds_1': {'jack': 11, 'joe': 13}}
players = list(score['rounds_0'].keys())
rounds = range(len(score.keys()))
print(f"          {''.join(f' **** Round {rd} **** ' for rd in rounds)} **** Total ****")
for player in players:
    scores = [score[f'rounds_{rd}'].get(player, 0) for rd in rounds]
    print(f"{player:10s}{''.join(f'{s:^20d}' for s in scores)}{sum(scores):^15d}")
```

Output:

```
           **** Round 0 ****  **** Round 1 ****  **** Total ****
jack               9                   11               20
joe                8                   13               21
```

Comment: Any way i can calculate total? too

Comment: i could upvote ans but i dont have reputation